# Click Event is executed automatically

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

I'm having this code

```
$(".menu").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("open").children("div").slideDown(200);
});

$(document).on('click', ".menu.open", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass("open").children("div").slideUp(200);
});
```

when I click the `.menu` the inner div slides down but it slides up again immediately and the open class is removed that's by only 1 click so how to fix this and make it work normal as a drop down menu for small screens opened by a click and closed by another click

Comment: Can you put that in a jsFiddle so we can try it out? Also, in this line, $(this).addClass("open");.children("div").slideDown(200); the first semi-colon seems out of place, can you double check your code?

Comment: it's just a typing mistake sorry about it problem presists

Comment: ok, no problem. Still need the fiddle. I think what's happening is that a click on .menu also triggers a click on .menu.open and that's why the close action is triggered when you click to open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the class `open` immediately on click and then sliding down-

```
$(".menu").on('click',function(e){
    $(this).addClass("open").........slideDown(200);
});
```

which is causing the delegated callback to be called. You should assign the class at the end of the animation and make sure you are not calling the `open` menu again -

```
$(".menu").on('click',function(e){
    var tthis = this; //saving the instance to refer in callback
    if ($(tthis).hasClass('open')){ //ignore if already open
         return;
    }
    $(tthis).children("div").slideDown(200, function(){
        $(tthis).addClass("open"); // add class at the end of the animation
    });
});

$(document).on('click',".menu.open",function(e){
    var tthis = this; //saving the instance to refer in callback
    $(tthis).children("div").slideUp(200, function(){
        $(tthis).removeClass("open"); // remove class at the end of the animation
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

in both

Comment: @Wally Altman good catch , but it still was not the correct answer , and I'll probably delete

Comment: It was worth a shot. :)